# PostgreSQL SELECT column names programmatically in python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I would like to pass programmatically few columns from python(psycopg2) in a table.

```
  cursor.execute("SELECT col1,col2,col3...coln FROM %s ORDER BY datetime ASC" %mytable)
```

column name col1,col2,col3...coln  can be of length 100's and change every time cursor.execute() is called.

Comment: I did a work around .                                                                           columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']                                                         columnsstr = ','.join(map(str, columns ))                                                querystring = 'SELECT ' + columnsstr + ' FROM %s ORDER BY timeentry ASC'
 cursor.execute(querystring %mytable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using string interpolation, so you could do the same for the column names. Put your column names in an array and join them when formatting the query:

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM %s ORDER BY datetime ASC" % (','.join(columns), mytable))
```

It is important that the columns are strictly controlled by you and not generated from user input, as that would enable SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Very crisp and concise answer. Thank you.